# Error : odbc_connect with php

Tags: php, sql-server, database, odbc

I have a problem is that I can't connect to the SQL Server database (with ODBC), I have the php_pdo_odbc driver on my extension folder and this line in file php.ini (extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll)

Code :

```
 <?php  

  $db_serveur = 'X.X.X.X'; 
  $db_user='user_demo';   
  $pwd = '';  
  $db_DSN = 'DSN_test'; 


  $conn= odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Serve};Server=$db_serveur;Database=$db_DSN;", 
  $db_user, $db_DSN);  ?>
```

error :

[image]

i have test this but the same problem :

$conn=odbc_connect($db_DSN,$db_user,$pwd);

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your connection line should be :

```
$dbConn = odbc_connect($dns, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);
```

Further, please have a look 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php

Comment: thank you for your answer but I tested it  $conn=odbc_connect($db_DSN,$db_user,$pwd);

Comment: but still I can not connect

Comment: Have you added your database in odbc connections (control panel -> search for odbc -> 32 or 64 -> Add connection Type etc

Comment: yes i have added this in my control panel ( I already worked with it with python and c #  without any problem)

Comment: OK then do in 2 steps. First just connect dsn. if connected then connect to db.

Comment: how i can do that ?

Comment: Means you need to try `odbc_connect` without database name. and then print_r that conn variable. If it shows connect then it means connection is correctly built. issue is with db

Comment: I have a proposal is that the connection odbc must be in data source system and not user (I will test that)

Comment: how can i send you the file?

Comment: <?php

$db_serveur = 'x.x.x.x'; 
$db_user='hamza';   
$pwd = '';  
$db_DSN = 'db_tets'; 

$conn=odbc_connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};server=$db_serveur;Database=$db_DSN;",$db_user,$pwd);
// $conn=odbc_connect($db_DSN,$db_user,$pwd);


if($conn) {
 echo "Connected";
}
else
{
 echo "erreur";
 //die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
} 

?>

Comment: OK let me try on my machine and then I will update you.